# iOS - how to set constraint from iPhone 7 to SE

Tags: ios, class, size, constraints

I've this big problem. iPhone 7 and SE uses the same size classes, so I cannot edit the constraints of SE. When I launch SE simulator, the app isn't optimized..in what way can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're very very low on details. Auto layout constraints *are* the correct thing to use in this situation - but without seeing any details on (a) what you are trying to do, (b) the constraints you've set on the various views, and (c) what you are seeing *versus* what you expect to see - well, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Well, in every controller there is something wrong when I switch from iphone 7 simulator to iphone SE simulator, for example a label, that on SE is cut and unfinished. I've already actived AutoLayaut on the first tab..

Comment: Straight auto layout means you are setting things like height/width and position (including centering) *independent* of size classes. (I do mine 100% in code but this is also the case in IB.) So again, without more details, I'm pretty sure you can see how difficult it is to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a label that is showing "some text..." on SE. There are a few ways you can solve this.

1. You could allow that label to be multiline
2. You could choose different text based on width
3. You could measure the text and if it's too big, use shorter text
4. You could pick something that fits on all widths
5. You could use the auto-font sizing features of labels
6. You could pick a font size yourself from the width or by measuring.

Constraints/Size-classes are not the only tool you can use for a responsive design.

The point of using size classes is not to solve this kind of problem -- it's to have a completely different UI -- like you show side-by-side panes on iPad and a navigation controller on iPhone.

Comment: You also could use equal widths and heights and percentage of the view multiplier to scale per device.